# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'request' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, bottle

I made a simple program using Bottle. Yet, im a getting an error:

```
@route('/login')
def login_form():
 return '''<form method="POST" action="/login">
            What do you want to search for?<br>
            <input name="search" type="text" />
            <input type="submit" />
          </form>'''

@route('/login', method='POST')
 def PeopleSearch():
  raw = request.forms.get('search')
  query = urllib.urlencode ( { 'q' : 'who is '+raw } )


response = urllib.urlopen ( 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&' + query   ).read()                           
json = m_json.loads ( response )
results = json [ 'responseData' ] [ 'results' ]

for result in results :
    url = result['url']
    return (url)
```

The imports are:

```
# -*- coding: cp1252 -*-
import codecs
from bottle import route, run, template, request
import Tkinter
from Tkinter import *
import turtle
import time
from xgoogle.search import GoogleSearch, SearchError
import urllib2
import urllib
import json as m_json
 import sys
from urllib import FancyURLopener
import time
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import json as simplejson

Soup = BeautifulSoup
from nltk import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize
from collections import Counter
from math import log10
# -*- coding: utf-8 *-*
```

Now this program is supposed to return url, but it doesn't. Also it throws the error i mentioned before. It works perfectly well when i don't run it on a webpage.

Comment: You aren't showing the relevant portions of the code. Somewhere you are doing some assignment inside a function, which fails because `request` isn't a local variable. Show the *full traceback* of the exception.

Comment: Your indentation looks wrong. The line `query = ...` and the line `response = ...` should be at the same level, no?

Comment: Also, `return` in a `for` loop is strange.

Comment: I'm also getting a unboundlocal error on something I'm importing correctly. I'm guessing it has to do with the way python is invoking this script

Comment: Where the code says `raw = request.forms.get('search')`, what do you think should be the value of `request`, and why? Where should it come from?

Answer (score 0):

-- Apologies -- I see that you have the tag `bottle` on your post. Perhaps you haven't imported the `request` module from bottle. Make sure you have:

```
from bottle import request, get
```

at the start of your script. I really like this web page (http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/tutorial.html) for bottle :)

---

Have you imported the `urllib.request` library, looks like you may not have? Try importing this at the start:

```
import urllib.request
```

Heaps of good info on this module in the docs: http://docs.python.org/3.4/library/urllib.request.html

Comment: I 've made all necessary imports, it worked before. It's not printing request.

Comment: I don't see an import for `get`, this is normally required to work with the HTTP request method. Have updated the answer to include `get`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're missing the `request` module import.

Do you have this at the top of your script?

```
from bottle import request
```

Comment: It throws an Error 500: Internal Server Error

Comment: If it was a missing import the error would have been `NameError: global name 'request' is not defined`, not an `UnboundLocalError`.